# Fetch multiple row from data frame based on condition in two dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am having two dataframe which has been load from excel and here is the sample:

```
df1:
EmpName End date    amount  hours   total quantity
emp1    date1         10    2        20
emp2    date2         20    3        60
emp3    date3         30    4        120
emp4    date4         40    5        200
emp5    date5         50    6        300
emp6    date6         60    7        420
emp7    date7         20    8        160
emp8    date8         30    1        30
emp9    date9         10    2        20
emp10   date10        40    4        160
```

df2:

```
EmpName End date    amount  hours   total quantity
emp2    date7       10      2       20
emp2    date4       20      3       60
emp1    date6       30      4       120
emp7    date1       40      5       200
emp4    date8       50      6       300
emp6    date3       60      7       420
emp5    date4       20      8       160
emp8    date5       30      1       30
emp9    date9       10      2       20
```

From the above two table i need to find if the `df1.empname` isin `df2.empname` and `df2.to_date` isin `df2.to_date` if both the above condition are true then fetch the respective values of df2-date, df2-amount and df2-hours.

I was able to get the condition to true but was not able to fetch the same.
code is here:

```
df1['Status'] = np.where(df1['EmpName'].isin (df2['EmpName']) & df1['End date'].isin (df2['End Date']), 'Found', 'Not Found')
df1.head()
```

I cannot merge both the dataset as each dataset has around 27k of rows. and if I merge using inner or outer the total row count is comming around 674502 rows × 50 columns and also after the above code is executed with some modification it is giving me wrong dataset information with the same rows and columns

Comment: Try this `df2.loc[df2.EmpName.isin(df1['EmpName']) & df2.EndDate.isin(df1['EndDate']),['EndDate','amount','hours']]`

Comment: Try df1.merge(df2, on = ['EmpName', 'End date']), default merge is inner.